# Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure usp_EditCourses, Line 19 Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_EditCourses]
 @coursename varchar(50)
,@description varchar(50)
,@fees int
,@active tinyint
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE tblcourses(coursename, description, fees, Active) 
SET coursename=@coursename, description=@description, fees=@fees, Active=@active

END
```

Comment: You should add a little context to your question and say what is wrong, and what you were trying to do, otherwise someone who wants to help has to go through everything to find out what could be wrong.

Comment: Maybe include line 19?

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` doesn't take a column list, so it might just be:

```
UPDATE tblcourses
SET coursename=@coursename, description=@description, fees=@fees, Active=@active
```

But that's going to affect *every* row in the table. Presumably, one or more of these parameters should be being used in a `WHERE` clause to specify which rows to update, e.g.

```
UPDATE tblcourses
SET description=@description, fees=@fees, Active=@active
WHERE coursename=@coursename
```

If you're trying to update an existing course based on the course name.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect UPDATE statement:

You should have

```
UPDATE tblcourses
SET coursename=@coursename, 
    description=@description, 
    fees=@fees, 
    Active=@active
```

This will work, but since you don't provide a WHERE clause it will update all the rows in tblcourses.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [SQL Server Update Syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177523.aspx)

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name=@value
WHERE condition
```

you dont need the column names next to tablename

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tblcourses SET coursename=@coursename,description=@description, fees=@fees, Active=@active WHERE yourColumn=@Parameter

Assuming you are trying to update tblcourses, add a where clause in your syntax.